# Slim Image Cropper With Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**View**

```
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php base_url();?>edituserpic" name="form_editpic" id="form_editpic" class="avatar">

    <div class="slim"
         data-label="Drop your avatar here"
         data-size="240,240"
         data-ratio="1:1">
        <input type="file" name="avatar" required />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload now!</button>

</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit_user_pic() {
    $data['baseurl']  = $this->config->item('base_url');

// Pass Slim's getImages the name of your file input, and since we only care about one image, postfix it with the first array key
    $image = $this->slim->getImages('avatar')[0];

    */       
// Grab the ouput data (data modified after Slim has done its thing)
    if ( isset($image['output']['data']) )
    {
        // Original file name
        $name = $image['output']['name'];
        // Base64 of the image
        $data = $image['output']['data'];

    }
}
```

I'm just stuck in server side how to save to get output image and save to database.

I am getting `$name` undefined. This mean output is empty.

If anyone used it and able to help that would be great.

Comment: Also add code what you tried.

Comment: Here is the plugin : http://slimimagecropper.com

Answer (score 2):

If you've setup to use a different name than `"slim"`, pass it along.

```
$images = Slim::getImages('avatar');
$image = $images[0];
```

It works for me.